# Not able to download Pdf/Excel with JQuery AJAX get request with some data sent with get request

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel-5, mpdf

I am trying to Send some data with GET/POST request to the server.

Then server prepares a PDF( using mpdf library) and sends it back to the client.

FrontEnd Code to Send GET/POST request with data is as follows.

```
$("#edit_setting").click(function () {
        $.ajax({
            url: "http://localhost:8000/get_pdf",
            type: "POST",
            data: {
                data : {
                    "abhinav" : "kumar keshari"
                }
            },
            headers: {
                'Accept': "application/json",
                'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getCookie(ACCESS_TOKEN),
            },
            success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
                let w = window.open('about:blank');
                w.document.open();
                w.document.write(data);
                w.document.close();
            },
            error: function (XMLHttpRequest, data) {
                console.log("something went wrong.");
                console.log(data);
                console.log(XMLHttpRequest.status);
                console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseJSON);
            }
        });
    });
```

On server side the Controller sends a PDF.

```
class DownloadPdfController
{
    public function store(Request $request){
        $data_received = $request->data;
        error_log(print_r($data_received,true));
        $mpdf = new \Mpdf\Mpdf();

        $mpdf->Bookmark('Start of the document');
        $mpdf->WriteHTML('<div>Section 1 text</div>');
        return $mpdf->Output();

    }
}
```

the pdf sent by the server is captured in **data** variable of the success callback of AJAX.

**I want the response ( stored in data variable ) to be opened in a new window so that the download process may begin. But this is not working . Instead Browser loads with a bunch of gibberish.**

If instead of Making a AJAX request, i make a get request using Browser Search Tab. The PDF Downloads Fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works

```
$.ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8000/get_excel",
        type: "POST",
        data: {data : list_of_tables},
        dataType: 'binary',
        xhrFields: {
            'responseType' : 'blob'
        },
        headers: {
            'Accept': "application/json",
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + getCookie(ACCESS_TOKEN),
        },
        success: function (data, textStatus, request) {
            alert("success in fetching data");
            let url = URL.createObjectURL(data);
            let $a = $('<a />', {
                'href': url,
                'download': 'document.xlsx',
                'text': "click"
            }).hide().appendTo("body")[0].click();

            // URL.revokeObjectURL(url);

        },
        error: function (XMLHttpRequest, data) {
            console.log("error in show_history");
            console.log(data);
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest.status);
            console.log(XMLHttpRequest.responseJSON);
        }
    });
```